# Parsing value from method to another method JNI (C++)

Tags: java-native-interface

Is it possible to make a call to another method like so?

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_A(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    int h = 0; 
    Java_B();
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_B(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    h++;
}
```

I know that the code doesn't make sense, but is the principle okay?

Comment: Java_B cannot see the local **h** from Java_A!

Answer (score 2):

Not *exactly* like that, because function `Java_A()` tries to call `Java_B()` with an argument list that doesn't match the latter's parameters.  But inasmuch as the question seems to be whether one native method implementation can call another directly, yes it can, just as it can call any other C function accessible to it.  Nothing inherently prevents that.

HOWEVER, the semantics of such a call are not equivalent to those of invoking a (native) method on the same Java object, whether from Java or natively via JNI.  A direct call bypasses any Java-side synchronization of the method, for example, and it is not polymorphic.  Additionally, in the direct-call case you're working with only one allotment of local references for both functions together.  There may be additional, similar considerations.